# String to TimeStamp in Java

Tags: java, datetime, date-formatting

In my Application, I have a requirement where user inputs a time string in this format: `HH:MM:SS`, which I need to format, parse and then show the difference (in seconds) between these entered string.

> static long MyTimeStamp(String str)

is a static method which returns a long value.

```
String TimeString1="10:30:15";
String TimeString2="10:30:45";

long t1 =  MyTimeStamp(TimeString1); 
long t2 =  MyTimeStamp(TimeString2);

long t3 = t1 - t2;
System.out.println(t3);
```

***O/P Should be 30 sec.***

Comment: What is `MyTimeStamp`?

Comment: And `long t3 = t1 - t2` will produce a compiler error. Additionally: What is your question?

Comment: @ManishSingh I asked about "your question", because you simply told us what your requirements are. You did not tell us what problems you have. Obviously, you got stuck at a very low language level (the `t1 - t2` part tells that). In that case let me suggest to continue learning the language basics. There are many tutorials out there.

Answer (score 2):

Try with [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class for parsing:

```
SimpleDateFormat dtf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
try {
    Date dtime = dtf.parse("23:34:12");
    System.out.println(dtime.toString());
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

You can calculate time differences using `Date` class:

```
SimpleDateFormat dtf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
try {
    Date t1 = dtf.parse("10:30:15");
    Date t2 = dtf.parse("10:30:45");
    System.out.println("Diff in seconds: " + ((t2.getTime()-t1.getTime())/1000));
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to show the declaration of dtf?

Comment: mention SimpleDateFormat object as well.

Comment: @NikhilTalreja I didn't paste `dtf` declaration! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
    public static long getMillis(String time){
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            Date d = df.parse(time);
            return d.getTime();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long t3 = (getMillis("10:30:45") - getMillis("10:30:15"))/1000;
        System.out.println(t3);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code -

```
        String TimeString1="10:30:15";
        String TimeString2="10:30:45";
         SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
         Date date1 = null;
         Date date2 = null;
         try {
             date1 = DATE_FORMAT.parse(TimeString1);
             date2 = DATE_FORMAT.parse(TimeString2);

             long diff = date2.getTime()-date1.getTime();
             System.out.println(diff/1000);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Output -

```
30
```